# Customize equation numbering on beamer

Tags: beamer

I have around 250 slides which I am not able to compile as a single project (due to long compilation time). I have decided to keep them as separate projects. Is there a way to start the equation numbering on a new project from the number 50? (So that I may merge these separate pdfs in the end)

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{equation}
   E=mc^{2}
   \end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addtocounter{equation}{49}`

Comment: Oh great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: LaTeX's `\includeonly` might be another approach to this.